# Async task gets UI stuck

Tags: android, multithreading

I have 2 async tasks (which does server requests) running just before i leave my activity.
sometimes the activity which runs this async tasks gets stuck until the async tasks finish, and sometimes the next activity shows and gets stuck until the async tasks finishes.

my question is how do i run this task in a way in which my activity's UI doesn't gets stuck (the UI is not dependable on the responses in the async tasks)

Comment: If your AsyncTask is long enough that may cause crashes , you can execute it separately inside BackgroundService

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling `AsyncTask.get()`  somewhere in your activities code. If you call it before the task has finished executing, it will wait untill it does finish (Thus making your UI get stuck).

Comment: actually i don't call AsyncTask.get() at all


the code:
`.
.
.
       new updateBeforeLeaving().execute(ii); 
      }
      finish();
}`

Comment: and inside updateBeforeLeaving() i call anouther async task and also no "...get()"

Comment: It is clear that somewhere in your code the task's thread blocks the UI thread. If you're not calling "get()", we will need to see some code to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: actually can't post code for confidentiality agreements. 
is it possible that the problem is caused because the async task is using the activity public variables and that is causing the activity not to exit until the async task is finished? if the answer is no- is there another alternative to async task which can make the job done?

Comment: What public variables? Members you declared in your `Activity` class? And an alternative to `AsyncTask` would be simply running the code in another thread. If your `AsyncTask` does not return any result, simply create a `Runnable` object and run it in a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

1. Create a ProgressDialog set it to indeterminate and show it.
2. Call AsyncTask1 and in its PostExecute call AsyncTask2. Make sure you need to call this onUiThread.
3. In Postexecute of Asynctask2, dismiss the Progress dialog and start the next Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start your next activity on the `onPostExecute()` of the first Async Task. And if you have an Async task in the new activity ,call it as the last item on your onCreate Method. Following these simple rules should help

Answer (score 0):

Write the code in `AsyncTask` `doInBackground()` only and call it. So that you can check whether it is accessing any UI.

eg: `TestAsync extends AsyncTask...`

```
TestAsync async = new TestAsync();
async.execute();
```

Try this.
Normally, `AsyncTask` should run in separate thread. If you create two instance. and call execute, It should execute independently. But there may be only one thread available, So it should wait(In lower version, pool size is 1.).

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) // API 11
void startMyTask(AsyncTask asyncTask) {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
    else
        asyncTask.execute(params);
}
```

Other way is, You should run it in normal Thread.

Answer (score -1):

you are must be calling 2 activities at a time in your activity

1. so either you must use synchronized class or function to call asynk task
2. or you must use singleton class to call that asynk task so that api is called in synchronized manner
3. as asynk task uses main ui thread to complete the task so that can be the reason that activity is getting stuck